# Which characters are allowed in a BigQuery STRING column (getting "UDF out of memory" error)

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dataframe containing receipt-data. The column `text` in my dataframe contains the text from the receipt and seems to be an issue when I try to upload the data to BigQuery using `df.to_gbq(...)` since it produces the error

```
GenericGBQException: Reason: 400 Resources exceeded during query execution: UDF out of memory.; Failed to read Parquet file /some/file. 
This might happen if the file contains a row that is too large,
 or if the total size of the pages loaded for the queried columns is too large.
```

According to the error-message it seems to be an "memory error", but I have tried to convert all characters in each text to an "a" (to see if the strings contained to many characters) but that worked fine i.e I doubt it is that.

I have tried converting all characters to `utf8` by

`df["text"] = df["text"].str.encode('utf-8')` (since according to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical) they should be so) but that failed. I have tried to replace "\n" with " " but that fails aswell.

It seems like there's some values in my receipt-text that causes some troubles, but It's very difficult to figure out what (and since I have ~3 mio rows, it takes a while to try each and every row at a time) - are there any values that are not allowed in a big-query table?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `chunksize` in `to_gbq` does not split up the chunks in the way I thought it did. Manually looping over the dataframe in chunks like

```py
CHUNKSIZE = 100_000
for i in range(0,df.shape[0]//CHUNKSIZE):
    print(i)
    df_temp = dataframe.iloc[i*CHUNKSIZE:(i+1)*CHUNKSIZE]
    df_temp.to_gbq(destination_table="Dataset.my_table",
    project_id = "my-project",
    if_exists="append",
    )
```

did the trick (setting `chunksize=100_000` did not work)